# Can these changes be reversed by changing temperature?

Tags: phase

1. An egg turning hard when boiled.
2. A spoon full of batter cooking on a hot griddle.

I said that they both cannot be reversed, because I think if you throw both the egg and batter into the freezer, it will freeze, but it will not be in its original form before you cooked both of them. Then again, I guess I could try this for real on my own but I don't know if that would be a good idea...

Answer (score 3):

---

Both processes involved the denaturation of proteins and complex reactions so is impossible reverse them **only** with a change of temperature.

---

## Boiling an Egg

Although in most case denaturation is not reversible there are some cases where it is.
However in the case of Egg white denaturation is irreversible ([see here](http://books.google.it/books?id=WSf1FFOTIYEC&pg=PA323&dq=egg+denaturation+reversible&hl=it&sa=X&ei=vav4UuK4GIee4wT83oGABg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=egg%20denaturation%20reversible&f=false)) and so the whole process is by the way irreversible.

## Cooking batter

The same for the batter even if is unclear which flours are used, and the composition of the batter  you can be sure that after cooking batter on a hot griddle surely some irreversible reactions occur: denaturation, [Maillard reaction](http://books.google.it/books?id=WSf1FFOTIYEC&pg=PA323&dq=egg+denaturation+reversible&hl=it&sa=X&ei=vav4UuK4GIee4wT83oGABg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=egg%20denaturation%20reversible&f=false), [Amadori rearrangment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amadori_rearrangement).

Answer (score -1):

1. When you boil an egg, you denature its proteins, changing their structure. It can't be reversed.
2. Once the butter is melted by heat, you can solidify back by freezing.

Comment: I am not sure for part 1. I guess reassociation (renaturation) is quite common both in proteins and nucleic acids.

Comment: Renaturation could be done on certain proteins (I'm not quite sure about egg proteins), under some conditions and if denaturation has not produce drastically changes.

Comment: The question refers to bAtter, not bUtter

Comment: In the case of 'batter', I think that after loosing a great part of the water of the mixture, the flour become 'toasted' and this involved chemical processes, not physical, so is mostly irreversible.